# Same functions on multiple similar csv files and output in a single csv file?

Tags: r, csv, plot, data-analysis

newbie in R here.

I found similar threads and tutorials about my problem, however as I wasn't capable of figuring out the solution to my problem and with my project deadline approaching i thought of reaching out for help.

I have multiple similar csv files with similar names (2fg, 20fg,...) in a single directory. They all contain data frames with 8 columns and 360 rows. The rows represent time and each col represents a series of measurements.

What I want to do is find the mean and sd for each column, then the collective mean and sd of those 8 means and finally plot a time series for each csv (each line with a different colour) and a histogram that compares the collective means (and sd) of all csvs.

So far I am able of finding the mean, sd and their collectives and plot the time series for a single csv file, using
`plot.ts(2fg, plot.type=c("single"), col=rainbow(ncol(2fg)))`

What i am searching for is a way to do all that on every csv in my directory, then plot the histogram that will compare the collective means and output the plots and the collective means and sds of each csv on a single xlsx or csv file.

The approach i was working on was putting all my csvs on a single list using

```
list <- list.files(pattern = "csv")
```

and then try to use lapply but i couldn't produce any results.

I hope i was clear enough and thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit:** following the suggestion made by @Len Greski in the comments I put all my files in a list also giving my data a header

```
    lista <- list.files(pattern = ".csv", full.names=TRUE)
myfiles <- lapply(lista,function(x) {
  y <- read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = FALSE, sep = ',',
                col.names = c("well_1", "well_2", "well_3", "well_4", "well_5",
                "well_6", "well_7", "well_8"))
  y$filename <- x
  y 
})
```

and then in a big data frame

```
 data <- do.call(rbind,myfiles)

 
# A tibble: 6 x 9
    well_1 well_2 well_3 well_4 well_5 well_6 well_7 well_8 filename          
       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>             
    1  0.158  0.218  0.152  0.189  0.205  0.190  0.181  0.153 ./1_s1_control.csv
    2  0.158  0.218  0.152  0.189  0.205  0.190  0.181  0.153 ./1_s1_control.csv
    3  0.158  0.218  0.152  0.189  0.204  0.190  0.181  0.153 ./1_s1_control.csv
    4  0.158  0.218  0.152  0.189  0.204  0.190  0.181  0.153 ./1_s1_control.csv
    5  0.159  0.218  0.151  0.189  0.204  0.190  0.181  0.153 ./1_s1_control.csv
    6  0.159  0.218  0.151  0.189  0.204  0.190  0.181  0.153 ./1_s1_control.csv
```

I then tried the following to calculate means and sd, but i got an error

```
    # summarise by file (filename)
    data2 <- data %>% 
      group_by(filename) %>%
      summarise(., across(c(well_1, well_2, well_3, well_4, well_5, well_6, well_7, well_8)),
                         list(mean = mean, sd = sd), .names = "{col}.{fn}")

Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In names(cols)[missing_names] <- names[missing_names] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any suggestions or corrections are welcome! :)

Comment: What was wrong with your `lapply` attempt? What exactly did you try? Because that is the right strategy. Examples here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790114/applying-same-function-on-multiple-files-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do all the tasks in the question except the plotting of time series and histograms. Since there is no reproducible example provided with the question, we'll use the [Pokémon Stats](https://github.com/lgreski/pokemonData) data that I have saved on Github, originally based on a Kaggle data set from Alberto Barradas.

Each file contains one generation of Pokémon, `gen01.csv` through `gen07.csv`. All files track 13 variables representing basic statistics for Pokémon, as illustrated below.

[image]

First, we'll download the data, unzip the zip file, obtain the list of file names, and read them with `lapply()` and `read.csv().

```
if(!file.exists("pokemonData.zip")){
     download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/pokemonData.zip",
                   "pokemonData.zip",
                   method="curl",mode="wb")
     unzip("pokemonData.zip")
}

thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",pattern="*.csv",
                              full.names=TRUE)

pokemonDataFiles <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) {
    y <- read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    # uncomment next line to add a column that stores the file name
    # y$fileName <- x
    y 
})
```

Next, we combine the seven data frames into a single data frame with `do.call()`.

```
# merge to single data frame
data <- do.call(rbind,pokemonDataFiles)
```

Since each file included a column, `Generation`, that maps to the files, we can use this variable with `dplyr::group_by()` to calculate means and standard deviations by file.

```
library(dplyr)
# summarise by file (generation)
data %>% group_by(Generation) %>%
     summarise(.,across(c(Total,HP,Attack,Defense,SpecialAtk,SpecialDef,Speed),
                        list(mean = mean, sd = sd), .names = "{col}.{fn}")) 


# A tibble: 7 x 15
  Generation Total.mean Total.sd HP.mean HP.sd Attack.mean Attack.sd Defense.mean
       <int>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1          1       426.     115.    65.6  28.1        76.5      30.8         70.7
2          2       418.     120.    71.2  30.6        72.0      32.7         73.4
3          3       436.     136.    66.5  24.1        81.6      36.6         74.1
4          4       459.     120.    73.1  25.1        82.9      32.8         78.1
5          5       435.     108.    71.8  22.4        82.1      30.4         72.3
6          6       436.     115.    68.3  20.9        75.8      29.2         76.7
7          7       461.     123.    71.3  26.9        87.1      33.9         79.3
# … with 7 more variables: Defense.sd <dbl>, SpecialAtk.mean <dbl>,
#   SpecialAtk.sd <dbl>, SpecialDef.mean <dbl>, SpecialDef.sd <dbl>,
#   Speed.mean <dbl>, Speed.sd <dbl>
```

We can calculate means and standard deviations across files by eliminating the `group_by()` function in the dplyr pipeline.

```
# summarise across generations
summarise(data,across(c(Total,HP,Attack,Defense,SpecialAtk,SpecialDef,Speed),
               list(mean = mean, sd = sd), .names = "{col}.{fn}")) 


  Total.mean Total.sd  HP.mean  HP.sd Attack.mean Attack.sd Defense.mean
1   437.6293 120.4411 69.43561 25.665    79.82643  32.70236     74.39194
  Defense.sd SpecialAtk.mean SpecialAtk.sd SpecialDef.mean SpecialDef.sd
1   31.32974        73.39866      33.11673        72.37066      27.96375
  Speed.mean Speed.sd
1   68.20605 29.28088
>
```

To address the plotting parts of the question we will need additional information from the person who posted the question.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestions! I edited my original question to include what i ve done so far as well as an image depicting part of my data. If you have any additional suggestions i would be more than happy to hear!

Comment: @greg - your code fails because you misplaced a right parenthesis, a subtle error. Try this instead: `summarise(., across(c(well_1, well_2, well_3, well_4, well_5, well_6, well_7, well_8),
                             list(mean = mean, sd = sd), .names = "{col}.{fn}"))`

Comment: you were absolutely right about the parenthesis! Now it's working perfectly thanks a lot!!

Comment: @greg - if you found my answer to be helpful, please accept it by checking the checkmark next to the answer, and by upvoting it.